# React.js: POSTMapping fetch from JavaSpring-boot backend sends request, but does nothing

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm the midst of creating a fullstack project consisting of a React-js frontend, a Java Spring-Boot backend, and an SQL database. I have a simple set of classes/interfaces/controllers set up for getting a list of objects in the database, as well as creating/deleting/modifying individual objects.

After linking the database and back-end and confirming all the controller requests were all functional, I tried to use them on the front-end. The GET requests all worked fine, but trying to use any request that required passing a **request body** did not seem to function. Here's how it went down:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAOFx.png)

First, here's a POSTMapping request in the back-end. I am using Autowired for these requests.

```
const createNewIS = (e) => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/ideas/create", {
        method: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'nology-brainstorm/json',
          'Content-Type': 'nology-brainstorm/json',
          'API-Key': 'secret'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "spaceid": 4,
            "name": newISName,
            "description": newISDesc
        })
    }).then((nothing) => {
        updateNewISPopUp(e);
    })
}
```

Second, here's the fetching function on the front-end. I have tried running this function without the API-Key header, without the .then() proceeding the first clause, and also without encapsulating the class's key names in speech marks. None of these seemed to have any effect, and the result was always as follows:

[Image 2 (Browser Console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LYs7.png)

The request seems to be made, and the body appears to have been successfully passed. But when I check the database or the state in my front-end that stores its retrieved objects, the new object is not added to it. Apologies if the solution is an obvious one here, but does anyone know why the request is not properly running? I have been looking at this for hours with no luck.

Comment: Kindly put code next time @Alice

Comment: Will make sure to copypaste code directly in next time, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

415 is Unsupported Media Type.   This is generally related to your Content-Type

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

You are passing a custom content-type, therefore you need to define it on your backend controller as well.

```
@PostMapping(path = "users", 
        consumes = "nology-brainstorm/json", 
        produces = "nology-brainstorm/json")
```

Comment: I tried adding the consumes and produces attributes to the request on the back-end controller, but it did not change the result; still a 415 error: 

@PostMapping(path = "/ideas/create",
    consumes = "nology-brainstorm/json",
    produces = "nology-brainstorm/json")

Comment: Please show your IdeaSpace class code @Alice

Comment: Here is the code for the class itself, if you meant the controller or interface instead my apologies.  https://pastebin.com/k2Y5RtXd